# In Thymleaf, How to break/exit the th:each loop once a condition is satisfied

Tags: java, html-table, thymeleaf

I am a Thymeleaf newbie, facing a scenario where I need to exit/break th:each loop once a specific condition is met.

```
<div th:each="appStatusModel, appStatusModelTemp : ${flow.latestAppStatus}" th:remove="tag">
<th:block th:switch="${appStatusModel.appStatus}">
    <td th:case="GREEN" style="border : 1px solid black" class="col-md-1 cellGreenEnv">
        <span th:text="${appStatusModel.appName}">AppName</span>
        <br></br>
        <span th:text="${appStatusModel.appEnv}">AppEnv</span>
    </td>
    <td th:case="GREY" style="border : 1px solid black" class="col-md-1 cellGreyEnv">
        <span th:text="${appStatusModel.appName}">AppName</span>
        <br></br>
        <span th:text="${appStatusModel.appEnv}">AppEnv</span>
    </td>
<div th:if="{appStatusModelTemp.index>5}" th:remove="tag">
    <td class="col-md-1 cellGreyEnv">
        <span>More</span>
    </td>
</div>
```

I want to break/exit the th:each loop for 'appStatusModelTemp.index>5'. 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the following,

```
<div th:each="appStatusModel, appStatusModelTemp :${flow.latestAppStatus}" th:remove="tag">
```

**appStatusModelTemp** is actually considered as the index, for example,

```
<tr th:each="prod,iterStat : ${prods}">
<tr>
```

So Change your **th:if** to the following,

```
<div th:if="${appStatusModelTemp<5}" th:remove="tag">
        <td class="col-md-1 cellGreyEnv">
            <span>More</span>
      </td>
</div>
```

with this **th:if** will only execute provided the index is less than 5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my issue is when appStatusModelTemp.index<5 I want to continue my iteration else for any appStatusModelTemp.index > 5, I want to break the loop and stop iterating. There are possibilities of having appStatusModelTemp size till 15.